# high cpu usage in boost::asio::io_service::run

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have encountered a strange problem with boost::asio::io_service::run. Sometimes this `run` function seems to eat the whole cpu(100%), and sometimes not. I am not very clear about the pattern.

the relevant code:

```
class Asio {
 public:
  Asio() :
      io_service_(new boost::asio::io_service),
      run_() {}

  void Start() {
    if (!asio_thread_.joinable()) {
      run_ = true;
      asio_thread_ = std::thread([=] {
        Run();
      });
    }
  }

  boost::asio::io_service* io_service() { return io_service_.get(); }

 protected:
  void Run() {
    for (;;) {
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      io_service()->run(ec);

      if (run_) {
        io_service()->reset();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

 protected:
  std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>    io_service_;
  std::thread                                 asio_thread_;
  std::atomic<bool>       run_;
};
```

When the `run` function runs normally, below is the callstack

```
#0  0x00000035f74e9163 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000b3f6ef in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(bool, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) ()                                       
#2  0x0000000000b40111 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) ()
#3  0x0000000000b3feaf in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#4  0x0000000000b403fd in boost::asio::io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#5  0x0000000000b3ddc1 in Asio::Run() ()
```

When the `run` function behaves abnormally, below is the callstack:

```
#0  0x00000031bbee53c9 in syscall () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f831d1d3d68 in std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::now() () from /usr/local/gcc48/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000000000b45b6d in boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::now() ()
#3  0x0000000000b45608 in boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> > >::get_ready_timers(boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) ()
#4  0x0000000000b3f5d7 in boost::asio::detail::timer_queue_set::get_ready_timers(boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) ()
#5  0x0000000000b3f815 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(bool, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) ()                                       
#6  0x0000000000b40111 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) ()
#7  0x0000000000b3feaf in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#8  0x0000000000b403fd in boost::asio::io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#9  0x0000000000b3ddc1 in Asio::Run() ()
```

In both cases, there're some pending handlers in the io_service, so the `io_service::run` should not return and should be wait for the event to happen.

Any advise is welcome.

I did further check, it's seems it's due to the boost::asio::steady_timer used. The usage of steady_timer involves the usage of the following pattern:

```
boost::asio::steady_timer timer;
timer.expires_at(some_expiry, error_code)
timer.async_wait((=)(boost::system::error_code ec) {
  // some operation
  timer.expires_at(new_expiry, error_code);
  timer.asyn_wait(...);
});
```

Where the timer is wrapped in a shared pointer, and it's safe to copy into the lamda function.

Comment: can you list all service implementations that you use (e.g. tcp socket, ssl socket, deadline timer, native handles, serial communications etc), and the platform (looks like linux, I guess)?

Comment: @sehe, comments added regarding the usage of boost::asio::steady_timer